# Artifactory Users Management not loading

Tags: artifactory, user-management, server-error

I'm trying to open the Artifactory Users Management page, following the Admin->Security->Users tab.

Then I'm getting the following error:

[image: Server Error]

Any idea of what might be causing it? Also, which log I can check this? Couldn't find anything yet.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include server log?

Answer (score 0):

The server error generally indicates there is problem fetching the user details from Artifactory. This can happen due to any of the following reasons:

1. when you have a high volume of users and the request is timing out.
2. There is a chance that you might have created a username with a
   special character which is not allowed (using the REST method or some
   other method)
3. There is an issue with the backend database

And the best place to troubleshoot is to first check the request log a good valid entry looks like below:
*20200715164402|104|REQUEST|165.225.104.49|admin|GET|/ui/users|HTTP/1.1|200|0*

Next check the artifactory.log file for java stack or check catalina.out under tomcat/logs directory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Much likely it's the reason #1.

I'll dig into the request log looking for that entry, see what I can find. Thanks!

Comment: just wanted to check if you were able to resolve the issue?